# Отображение текста вкладок при использовании Vue3 component :is

Tags: vue.js, vue3

во Vue3 при использовании условного рендера компонентов component: is  во вкладке отображается имя компонента. Пару недель бьюсь над тем, чтобы добиться отображения во вкладке нужного мне текста...

[Стандартный пример использования](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

опираясь на данный пример - нужно чтобы, например, вкладка "Home" отображалась как "Домашняя"

единственный вариант, который я нашёл - это в дочернем компоненте

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Домашняя",
}
</script>
```

и принимать в родительском компоненте по этому имени. работает.
НО! 1. Лид говорит, что использовать имя компонента не должно задействоваться для отображения контента
2. если для передачи currentTab используется vuex (вкладки в одном компоненте, компоненты в другом) то ничего не работает..

пс. просьба сильно не бить, обучаюсь фронтенду только полтора месяца)

Comment: Расширьте массив строк, до массива объектов 

[{key:"Home",title:"Домашняя"}, {key:"Posts",title:"Статьи"}, {key:"Archive",title:"Архив"}]

Используйте как объект, например
{{ tab.title }}
<component :is="currentTab" class="tab.key"></component>

Ну и имейте ввиду что тепереь это объекты и учтите это во всей логике

P.S. Не учу что правильно, а что нет, это как одно из решений для ващей задачи

Comment: спасибо!!! на самом деле вокруг да около этого решения ходил, но не мог понять как воплотить) всё работает, в том числе и через vuex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расширьте массив строк, до массива объектов

```
  [
    {
      key: 'Home',
      title: 'Домашняя',
    },
    {
      key: 'Posts',
      title: 'Статьи',
    },
    {
      key: 'Archive',
      title: 'Архив',
    },
  ]
```

И используйте как объект, например:

```
  {{ tab.title }}

  <component :is="currentTab" class="tab.key" />
```

Ну и имейте ввиду что тепереь это объекты и учтите это во всей логике

P.S. Не учу что правильно, а что нет, это как одно из решений для вашей задачи